# Can eldoc display in a dedicated window?

Tags: eldoc, dedicated-windows

Currently `eldoc` pops up a window, mostly it's fine but with large docs it gets intrusive & jarring to loose so much screen space.

Is there a way to have eldoc use it's own dedicated window? (which could be empty or closed when not in use?)

Comment: Will `popwin` not work?

Comment: Perhaps? This is the first I've heard of it.

Comment: Please check https://github.com/emacsorphanage/popwin/. It allows you more control on popup windows, and maybe it can address your issue?

Comment: In a comment that I have since deleted, I referenced the function `eldoc-minibuffer-message`, and on further examination of the `eldoc.el` library, I saw a variable that is customizable called `eldoc-message-function`, which can be used to substitute your custom function instead of `eldoc-minibuffer-message`.  However, I see no reference in the `eldoc.el` library to popping up a window.  Are you sure `eldoc.el` is the library responsible for popping up a window that you are seeing?